# I have an Issue With Java! Scottrade!

Tags: 12.04, java, openjdk

My problem is that I downloaded a file with the the extension .jnlp . I have the necessary installed requirements Java Runtime Environment (JRE) 7 openjdk. When I try to open the necessary/required downloaded Scottrade.jnlp file, it processes the request, but I get an error. Here is more data https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/+bug/1385639. I don't know why it's not working. But if you have any details toward fixing this issue. Please advice me.
System Spec: Ubuntu 12.04, 64 bit, system is up to data
Thank You
 Here is the error message that I received !

```
net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Initialization Error: Could not initialize application. 
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplication(Launcher.java:778)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launchApplication(Launcher.java:552)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:889)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Application Error: Cannot grant permissions to unsigned jars. Application requested security permissions, but jars are not signed.
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.setSecurity(JNLPClassLoader.java:289)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.<init>(JNLPClassLoader.java:209)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:323)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplication(Launcher.java:770)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: 
net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Application Error: Cannot grant permissions to unsigned jars. Application requested security permissions, but jars are not signed.
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.setSecurity(JNLPClassLoader.java:289)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.<init>(JNLPClassLoader.java:209)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:323)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplication(Launcher.java:770)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launchApplication(Launcher.java:552)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:889)
```

Comment: I think you should install Oracle Java instead of OpenJDK

Comment: Use [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html) link to check  how to install JDK 7

Comment: If this will help, please write selfanswer here